# How to use the ksql-jdbc-driver to access the kstream or ktable

Tags: ksqldb

I am now trying to use the KSQL-JDBC-driver to access to Ksql stream. I got stuck when using the driver, Can anyone give me a hand. Many thanks

import com.github.mmolimar.ksql.jdbc.KsqlConnection;

import com.github.mmolimar.ksql.jdbc.KsqlConnectionValues;

import com.github.mmolimar.ksql.jdbc.KsqlDriver;

import com.github.mmolimar.ksql.jdbc.KsqlStatement;

import scala.None;

import java.sql.*;

import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("com.github.mmolimar.ksql.jdbc.KsqlDriver");

    String url="jdbc:ksql://localhost:8089";

    KsqlDriver kd= new KsqlDriver();

    System.out.println(kd.acceptsURL(url));

    KsqlConnection con = kd.buildConnection(KsqlDriver.parseUrl(url), null);

    con.validate();

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from KSQLTEST");

      while(rs.next()){

      System.out.println(rs.getString(0)+" ： "+rs.getInt(1));

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about the JDBC driver. FYI, there is a new Java client: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-clients/java-client/